# block hash and list since block?

Tags: client, bitcoind

I am writing transaction monitoring service but I am having some problems with listing since block hash. I have bitcoind daemon and when I execute listTransactions some transactions have same block hash so if I would try to listSinceBlock I would have problems. How this all works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block hash identifies a block. A block can contain multiple transactions, so `listsinceblock` lists all transactions in blocks newer than the given block hash.

So f.e., if you have this block structure:

```
block 5 hash: qwertyyuiop
|   tx100,tx101,tx102,tx103
v
block 6 hash: asdfghjklkl
|   tx104,tx105,tx106,tx107,tx108
v
block 7 hash: zxcvbnmnbvc
    tx109,tx110,tx111
```

When you would do `listsinceblock qwertyyuiop`, you would get all transactions in blocks older than block 5, so `tx104` all the way up to `tx111`.

Comment: How long one block hash last? So how often is block hash changed?

Comment: The hash of a block does never change. It's its identifier, every block has a unique block hash.